# PHP PDO returning null column names

Tags: php, mysql, soap, pdo, bindparam

I am developing SOAP service in PHP.
Recently I have came across an issue when retrieving results from MySQL.
**Problem**
When retrieving results I get more columns than specified in my SQL statement. This is affecting my code when processing retrieved information. For example when I change `fetch()` to `fetchAll()`, I can't process more than one record. Is there any way to tell `PHP` or `MySQL` to return EXACTLY the columns that I need and not return this rubbish?
**example code**

```
$stmt2 = $pdo2->prepare("SELECT `id`, `username`, `IP_address` FROM PADR_users WHERE `username` LIKE :username");
$stmt2->bindParam(':username',$searchParam, PDO::PARAM_STR, 20);
$stmt2->execute();
$tmp = $stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$response->return = var_export($tmp, true);
```

This will produce:

```
object(stdClass)#4 (1) { ["return"]=> string(193) "array ( 'id' => '19', 'username' => 'Batman2', 'IP_address' => '192.168.0.1' . "\0" . '' . "\0" . '' . "\0" . '' . "\0" . '' . "\0" . '' . "\0" . '' . "\0" . '' . "\0" . '' . "\0" . '', )" }
```

Before I call MySQL I also tried using these:

```
$pdo2->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$pdo2->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS, PDO::NULL_NATURAL);
```

However it doesn't make even a slightest difference.
**Note**
I have left intentionally the `fetch()` and not `fetchAll()` to eliminate possibility that the implementation of `fetchAll()` could have influenced the results.

Comment: `"%".$searchParam."%"` should be like that

Comment: That looks like some bad information in your database for the IP address. Verify it on the command line or in PHPMyAdmin, and try trimming it before inserting it. And just assign your result instead of using var_export.

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile I have done that, the same invalid results.

Comment: @aynber `IP_address` is a `varchar` and is no different than the `username`.

Comment: Yes, but those 0's are null bytes.

Comment: True, these null bytes I am NOT selecting, as you can see the query specifically asks for 3 columns. Is there a reason for the driver to IGNORE sql syntax or is that an undocumented feature of `PHP` lol

Comment: The null bytes are a part of your IP address field, not another field. You can tell by the concatenation symbol (period) `'IP_address' => '192.168.0.1' . "\0"`

Comment: I see!!! This would mean that the data contained in the database has that in there. Well spotted !! I will investigate it now. Thanks

Comment: @aynber bravissimo ! that did it. I inserted nulls into the columns and it is now returning multiple results! If you can put that as an answer I'll be sure to accept it.

Comment: A new SOAP service in 2017? That's an unusual thing to see.

Comment: Security is not an old topic ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only retrieving only 3 columns. However, the IP address has some null data at the end of it. You can tell by the concatenation operator between the strings:

```
'IP_address' => '192.168.0.1' . "\0" . '' . "\0" . '' . "\0" . '' 
                              ^      ^    ^      ^    ^      ^
```